# Вызываю функцию PHP с обработчиками кнопок, а они срабатывают сами по себе

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, веб-программирование

Я вызываю функцию, где я устанавливаю евент нажатия на кнопки. Но если я ее вызываю, то if срабатывает сам по себе и из за рекурсии происходит бесконечный цикл. Тоесть я вызываю функцию, в ней ставятся слушание кнопок, нажимая на кнопку я должен вызывать эту же функцию, передавая другие параметры. Подскажите пожалуйста простым для новичка языком.

```
<?php
require "php/include_db.php";
$src = null;

$locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', 1);
$src = $locationInfo->location_image;
echo $src;
setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);

function setButton($locationInfo_travel)
{
    $arr_travels = explode(' ', $locationInfo_travel);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_travels); $i++) {
        echo ", ", $arr_travels[$i];
    }

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';

    if (!empty ($_POST['location_button_1'])) {
        $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[0]);
        $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
        echo $src;
        setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
    }
    if (!empty ($_POST['location_button_2'])) {
        $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[1]);
        $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
        echo $src;
        setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
    }
    if (!empty ($_POST['location_button_3'])) {
        $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[2]);
        $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
        echo $src;
    }
    if (!empty ($_POST['location_button_4'])) {
        $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[3]);
        $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
        echo $src;
    }
}

?>
```

Форма:

```
<div class="location_buttons_container">
    <div class="buttons_container">
        <form method="post" action="Game.php">
            <ul class="buttons_menu">
                <li>Локации</li>
                <li ><span ><button id="location_button_1" name="location_button_1" value="selected">Главные ворота</button></span><em>3 сек.</em></li>
                <li><span><button name="location_button_2" value="selected">Торговый квартал</button></span><em>2 сек</em></li>
                <li><span><button name="location_button_3" value="selected">Замок</button></span><em>5 сек</em></li>
                <li><span><button name="location_button_4" value="selected">Гильдия</button></span><em>4 сек</em></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отформатируй код. Третий раз задаешь вопрос и какая-то лапша непонятная.

Comment: @КириллВеликий Причем тут "не знаешь". Просьба вполне корректная. В таком виде код представлять - это издевательство и неуважение к тем, кто пытается помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй заменить !empty, на isset.
Чтобы было примерно так:
`if(isset($_POST['location_button_3']))`
Это проверка на нажатие будет тогда

Comment: Делал так, получается тоже самое

Comment: Разве после `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';` не должна закрываться функция setButton? А то для location_button_1 она вызывает сама себя

Comment: Нет, так и должно быть. Она должна вызывать себя, передавая разные параметры

Comment: Привет ещё раз, потыкался с твоим кодом, в общем. Данная строка `setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);` И создает бесконечный цикл, условно: Ты нажимаешь на кнопку 1( Главные ворота), php видит на 8 строчке `setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);` запускает функцию( если по твоему коду нажимать 1 или 2 кнопку) то в функцию она вызывает ещё одну функцию, как ты и написал, происходит рекурсия из-за вызова функцией самой себя, т.е. будет вызывать так постоянно.

Comment: Попробуй убрать вызов самой себя, может быть сделать какое-нибудь нажатие->вывод информации(или какое там действие тебе нужно)-> редирект на index.php твой файл с html

Comment: Воот, а мне нужно, что бы она при вызове самой себя останавливалась и снова ждала нажатия. Как мне это сделать, бро?

Comment: Попробуй вот так изменить код где в if `echo $src;
unset($_POST['location_button_1']);
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);` В общем попробовать удалять значение этой переменной, и тогда не будет зацикливаться.

Comment: Только не уверен, что будет опять нажатия ждать. Отпишись потом

Comment: Вроде что то есть.. Спасибо, брат

Comment: Реально потом нажатие не слушает

Comment: У тебя `$locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[0]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;` $locationinfo- это закидывание какой-то инфы в БД, а $src - вывод картинки?

Comment: И эти действия нужно будет делать каждый раз при нажатии кнопки, верно?

Comment: Или всё получилось?

Comment: Нужно, но все же нет. Ты был прав, кнопки не слушаются с unset

Comment: То есть слушает только первое нажатие, а потом нет. Хм. Я подумаю, отпишу завтра, как время будет.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо тебе большое за помощь

Comment: Слушай, я немного переписал код(проблема осталась.) Может мы сможем связаться по вк, например, я постараюсь объяснить задумку кода и что не так, может поможешь найти более хорошие варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю вы делаете GET запрос на файл Game.php для показа самой формы. В этом случае добавьте проверку на пустой массив $_POST перед вызовом setButton на восьмой строке:

```
if(empty($_POST)) {
   setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
 }
```

Аналогично можно проверить какой тип запроса пришёл через

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
   setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
 }
```

**Объяснение**

POST запрос отсылается при отсылке формы, а GET запрос - для получения HTML содержимого файла, которое выводится у вас через echo. Код выше решит вашу проблему с вызовом функции, которая должна быть вызвана только при GET запросе на указанном месте (остальные вызовы остаются как есть)

Comment: А что мне это даст?

Comment: Я понял. А как это поможет исправить мою проблему?